# Помогите определить причину Kernel Panic в Debian

Tags: debian, kernel, gdb

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема: иногда во время загрузки файла (архива, каталога, не важно) либо на облако или внешние ресурсы (реже по локальной сети), происходит Kernel Panic. Удалось получить дамп ядра. Его содержимое:

```
crash: invalid kernel virtual address: 0  type: "fill_thread_info"

crash: invalid task address: ffff8801f99d1380

crash: invalid kernel virtual address: 0  type: "fill_thread_info"

crash: invalid task address: ffff8801f99d0780
      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/vmlinux-4.3.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/201605021719/dump.201605021719  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 4
        DATE: Mon May  2 17:19:22 2016
      UPTIME: 03:39:47
LOAD AVERAGE: 0.22, 0.49, 0.45
       TASKS: 485
    NODENAME: Debian-PC
     RELEASE: 4.3.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Debian 4.3.5-1~bpo8+1 (2016-02-23)
     MACHINE: x86_64  (3192 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 7.8 GB
       PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff8801f9a43000"
         PID: 0
     COMMAND: "swapper/2"
        TASK: ffff88023223a180  (1 of 4)  [THREAD_INFO: ffff880232240000]
         CPU: 2
       STATE: TASK_RUNNING (PANIC)
```

Сначала думал, что дело в Zswap. Отрубил его - ситуация не изменилась. Происходит такое не часто, поэтому назвать примерную периодичность невозможно. Может неделю нормально всё работать, и потом упасть. Система Debian 8.4, ядро 4.3 (пробовал более новые, но Crash не читает их дампы). Система также обновлена из бэкпортов.

Comment: Ну это явно не весь дамп. Как получите весь, сразу же отправляете его линуху торвальду.

Answer (score 1):

Может диск посыпался на котором SWAP раздел размещён?

Comment: Почитайте как работает zSwap. Хорошая вещь :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев как хорошая вещь спасёт от сбойного чтения? мне не понятно.